# Open application settings with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

How to open application Settings page using Android Navigation Component?

I can open application Settings from code by sending Intent with URI of my application package name:

```
val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
intent.data = uri
startActivity(intent)
```

How to do the same thing but using Android Navigation Component?

Answer (score 0):

`android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` is equals to `android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` String. And package URL is just your application package (applicationId) with `package:` scheme: `package:com.example.application`

1. Create `activity` tag inside navigation graph with corresponding intent action and data.

   ```
   <activity
       android:id="@+id/app_settings"
       app:action="android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"
       app:data="package:com.example.application"
   />
   ```
2. Create `action` tag inside navigation graph with previously created activity

   ```
   <action
       android:id="@+id/action_global_to_app_settings"
       app:destination="@id/app_settings"
   />
   ```
3. Navigate to created action with Navigation Component

   ```
   navController.navigate(NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalToAppSettings())
   ```